# Why is beautiful soup returning ascii codes instead actual character when I output it with HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, django-views, beautifulsoup, httpresponse

I am reading an html file from storage directory, making some alterations with beautiful soup and then outputting the result using HttpResponse. My problem is that some of the characters such as the <> symbols are being returned as ascii codes instead of symbols e.g. < instead of <

To remove any chance that changes I am making using BeautifulSoup I simplified it down to the basics.  This works:

```
file = default_storage.open(fileLocation, 'r')
html = file.read()

HttpResponse(html)
```

This does not:

```
file = default_storage.open(fileLocation, 'r')
html = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

HttpResponse(str(soup))
```

This by no means represents my only attempt at this.  I have combed through the BeautifulSoup documentation and tried several different encoding methods, but with the same result.

Comment: Did you consider lxml.html (http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) at all?

Comment: no, but I will give it a look.

Comment: I have read over the lxml.html docs, but they seem a little light on examples. I need to be able to iterate over tags get the value of their attributes, change attribute values and inject content. Iteration is no problem, but there seems to be no examples of how to get and edit attribute (e.g. src).

Comment: Have you tried printing it into console or file instead of giving to `HttpResponse`?

Comment: bs3, unfortunatly I don't have control over the version